# What is the difference between Power Saver and Energy Saver?

Tags: windows-8, lenovo-laptop, power-options

My Lenovo Yoga laptop has three power options in mobility center.

- Power Saver
- Energy Saver
- High Performance

What is the difference between Power Saver and Energy Saver options? I'm using Windows 8.1 Pro.

Comment: "Energy saver" option is only available to you. (i.e it is specifically for your laptop model and has customized settings of power options)

Answer (score 2):

Energy saver is the old 'balanced' plan.
To see the differences, click change settings on any of them.

Answer (score 0):

one difference is that power saver automatically changes (reduces) the  brightness level of your computer/laptop. In other words it lowers it when you press "power saver". (For windows 7)